# Reading up on $BQP = BPP^{BQNC}$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, quantum-computing

What should I read to understand this problem?

> The power of small-depth quantum
>   circuits. Is $BQP = BPP^{BQNC}$? In other
>   words, can the "quantum" part of any
>   quantum algorithm be compressed to
>   polylog(n) depth, provided we're
>   willing to do polynomial-time
>   classical postprocessing? (This is
>   known to be true for Shor's
>   algorithm.) If so, building a
>   general-purpose quantum computer would
>   be much easier than is generally
>   believed! Incidentally, it's not hard
>   to give an oracle separation between
>   $BQP$ and $BPP^{BQNC}$, but the question is
>   whether there's any concrete function
>   "instantiating" such an oracle. --Scott Aaronson
>   http://www.scottaaronson.com/writings/qchallenge.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This was conjectured by R. Jozsa in Section 8 of [arXiv:quant-ph/0508124](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0508124). If you are already familiar with quantum computing and quantum complexity theory, you can start by reading that section.

An important reading is [arXiv:quant-ph/0006004](http://arXiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0006004), where Cleve and Watrous show that Shor's algorithm is in that class.