# Lower bounds for quantum circuits using the geodesic framework

Tags: quantum-computing

Some of us have been reading [Michael Nielsen's paper](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9304/lower-bounds-for-quantum-circuits-using-the-geodesic-framework) on a geometric approach to using quantum lower bounds (in brief, the construction of a Finsler metric on $SU(2^n)$ such that the geodesic distance from $I$ to an element $U$ is a lower bound on the number of gates in a quantum circuit that computes $U$).

I was wondering if there were concrete examples of problems where this program led to a lower bound that came close to, matched or beat prior lower bounds obtained by other means ?

One example that Joe Fitzsimmons provided is [this paper on optimal transfer rates in spin chains](http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.0378). While it's a good example of the "spirit" of the original idea, I'm specifically looking for methods that use Nielsen's program to provide **lower bounds**.

Comment: I could suggest to see "introduction" sections to papers such as http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.5968 and http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0603160 for list of references and some terms ...

Comment: This was apparently posted to some other SE site as a crosspost of a CS theory question, which then got merged back with CS theory!

Comment: ok that's very weird !